# Is the number of row operations to get to row echelon form fixed?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was looking at LU factorization (with no row exchanges) and it struck me how the multipliers $\it l_{ij}$ remain unchanged in the L matrix. I was then wondering if this means that the amount of row operations needed to get any matrix to row echelon form is already predetermined and if there were any formal proofs of this. I'm still a noobie in the subject, be gentle with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for a $n\times n$-matrix you can bound the number of row operations by $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ without counting row exchanges.

Because of the structure of [Gauß elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightedge_and_compass_construction#Constructing_regular_polygons) you perform $(n-1)+(n-2)+\ldots+2+1=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ row operations using that method.

However there are other procedures to compute LU decomposition that are not based on **row operations** and overall have less **arithmetic operations** compared to Gauß elimination. Gauß elimination can be shown to take about $\frac{2}{3}n^3$ arithmetic operations (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computational_efficiency)), while other methods use asymptotically less arithmetic operations as indicated in [another wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Theoretical_complexity).

Comment: Thanks very much! Super quick as well!